# Android java create new tiled bitmap from existing bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

OK so here is what I'm looking to do. I have an app that loads small bitmap images with a pattern that I'd like to use as my phones background (not the app background) Problem is when I set it as a wallpaper now using wallpapermanager it stretches the image and it looks horrible. Is there anyway I can either a) using wallpaper manager to tile the image so it looks nice or b) create another tiled bitmap from the small bitmap and use that. Suggestions?

Comment: Solved it using this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695710/android-development-combining-small-tiles-bitmaps-into-one-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

find the dimensions of your screen. Edit the picture using http://pixlr.com/editor/ if you dont have photoshop.

Comment: I should have been more specific. It is not one specific image. There are numerous and you can select which you like

Comment: umm, how about making an app to do tiling, then screenshot it and use it as a wallpaper?

Comment: Huh? No here is what happens. You open the app it loads a bunch of images in a listview. You click on the one you like and it sets the image as a wallpaper. Everything works BUT problem is the images are too small and I need to tile it somehow.