# How to create rounded view with multiple images

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

How would I go about creating a view that could contain multiple images and contain a circular border? Here are a few samples of what the end product would look like.

[image]
[image]

The images will be downloaded from a url, and as shown in the samples, there could be from one to four images contained in the view.

Comment: use custom `Drawable` which draws 4 or 2 `Bitmap`s in its `draw` method

Comment: @pskink how would I go about doing that? Are there any guides you can point me to? Thanks!

Comment: yes, see the sources of `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Comment: @pskink the only issue is that I'm getting these images from online, so I'm not sure how easy it will be to preload them before the Drawable's onDraw method

Comment: this is what `Drawable#invalidateSelf` is for, call it when the images are downloaded and ready to `Canvas#drawBitmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to create a custom `LinearLayout` that contains your four `ImageViews` in xml and could dynamically reorganize how many `ImageViews` are shown using weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_container"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_left_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#111" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_left_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#333" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_container"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_container"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_right_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#555" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_right_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#777" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/transparent_circle_image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You mentioned that you were loading the images from urls so if you used this approach you would be able to use a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the images and you wouldn't have to worry about waiting for all images to download before drawing the rounded image. If you did this each image could be loaded independently of the others.

The only downside would be that you would have to use a image with a transparent circle background to create the appearance of a circular image. You could just create a regular drawable to use. Or you could try drawing it onto a canvas. This [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589267/draw-a-transparent-circle-onto-a-filled-android-canvas) has a good solution that will create a custom view that draws a transparent circle.

If you want to use the custom view just replace

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/transparent_circle_image"/>
```

with

```
<com.app.view.TransparentCircle
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Love it! Last question - how should I most efficiently create the image with a transparent circle background?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a link to another question that implements a custom view for a transparent circle. Either use that or just create a regular image to use.

Comment: No problem, best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of good 3rd partly libraries that you can use for this creating circular images. But beforehand you will want to combine the multiple images into one rectangular one that can then be made circular.

I would look at either [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) or [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). The difference being what their name describes where `CircleImageView` will give you a perfectly circular image. `RoundedImageView` can actually provide rounded corners in the form of a rectangle, oval, or circle.

If you are trying to keep your app lightweight and avoid using outside libs you can also just create a circular image with a transparent circle in the middle that can be overlayed as the background image on top of a source image using a regular `ImageView`.

Comment: Can I put multiple images in the CircleImageView library? It doesn't seem like there is support for that yet

Comment: @AnkitGoyal dont use any external libs: just see how it is done in `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Comment: Just edited my answer, you'll want to combine the images into a rectangle first. Then use one of those libs.

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker Awesome- thanks. Should I combine the bitmaps like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6696001/1467730

Comment: I am not the best at drawing bitmaps @AnkitGoyal, but that looks like a good place to start.